# javafxにての実行後のエラー

Tags: java, javafx

JavaFxでチェックボタンを押すとラベルに画像が表示されるウインドウを作っていますが、実行すると以下のエラーが出てきます。画像の問題かなと自分では思っています。

画像のとおり、Eclipse内で、同じsrc内に、1414406.jpgを置いて、引数の部分も1414406.jpgと書き直して実行したのですが、エラーが出て表示されません。追記になりますがよろしくお願いします。

[image]

エラーメッセージ

```java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1128)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:706)
    at lesson4.SampleP2.start(SampleP2.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application lesson4.SampleP2
```

該当のコードは以下の通りです。

```java
package lesson4;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleP2 extends Application {
    private Label lb;
    private CheckBox ch;
    private Image im;
    private ImageView iv;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception
    {
        Label lb = new Label("This is me");
        CheckBox ch = new CheckBox("画像の表示");
        im = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("file:///C:/Users/USER/Pictures/1414406%20.jpg"));
        iv = new ImageView(im);

        lb.setGraphic(new ImageView(im));

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

        bp.setCenter(lb);
        bp.setBottom(ch);

        lb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        bp.setCenter(lb);
        //イベントハンドラの登録
        ch.setOnAction(new SampleEventHandler());

        Scene sc =new Scene(bp,500,500);

        stage.setScene(sc);

        stage.setTitle("サンプル");
        stage.show();
    }

    class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            CheckBox tmp = (CheckBox)e.getSource();
            if(tmp.isSelected() == true) {
                lb.setGraphic(iv);
            }
            else if(tmp.isSelected() == false) {
                lb.setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
```

Comment: 編集しているソースコードは "lesson4" の下みたいですが、指定した画像ファイルは別フォルダの "lesson5" の下にあるためうまく参照できていないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: lesson5の下ではなく、同じプロジェクト内に保存しています。

Answer (score 0):

[リソースの名前の指定方法](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))が誤っています。

具体的にはこの部分

```java
im = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("file:///C:/Users/USER/Pictures/1414406%20.jpg"));
```

で、引数に指定するのは[リソース名](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html#res_name_context)であり、ファイル名(ファイルシステム上の名前)ではありません。

解決策の一例として、`1414406%20.jpg` という名前のファイルはクラスパス上に存在している`SampleP2.class`と同じ場所においた上で、

```java
im = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("1414406%20.jpg"));
```

と書き換えることで画像が表示できるようになると思います。

おそらく、参考にされているドキュメントに画像の保存場所についての言及もあるかと思いますので、読み返してみてください。

---

(追記)

スクリーンショットのパッケージ構成の場合であれば `"/lesson5/1414406.jp"` と指定することになります。